# Windows 10 App Store - where are logs?

Tags: windows-10

Please, can you say me where can I found logs from W10 Store - when and who install app? I seen in Event logs - Application - but I think, that only MSI installer there are.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

To access the Windows Store debug logs on Windows 10, open the Event Viewer, and then click on the arrows in the left column to navigate to:

1. Applications and Services
2. Microsoft
3. Windows
4. Store
5. Operational

[image: Event Viewer example]

Answer (score 2):

If you open up command promp type => **wscollect** 
In a few seconds it will say **Done**
There will then be a file on your desktop called StoreLogs with the date. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From MS docs:

> To access the packaging and deployment event logs by using Event Viewer, follow these steps:
>
> Perform one of the following steps:
>
> Click Start on the Windows menu, type Event Viewer, and press Enter.
> Run eventvwr.msc. In the left page, expand Event Viewer (Local) >
> Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows.
>
> Check for available logs under these categories:
>
> AppxPackagingOM > Microsoft-Windows-AppxPackaging/Operational
> AppXDeployment-Server >
> Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer/Operational

and

> Additionally, the following event entries are logged in the
> "Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational" log under Applications and
> Services\Microsoft\Windows\Apps

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting

There's a Powershell command to list latest logs

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxlog?view=win10-ps

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no such log recorded in event log. It will only record the log like app is not started or launched successfully etc. You could see Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log path to know well.

If you want to know when install, please launch the Windows Store, click the see more button... , then click My library 
[image]